# Java Spring JPA magical update

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am having two Entities:
**Aircraft**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
//@ToString
public class Aircraft extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private Airport airport;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

And **Airport:**

```
public class Airport extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String identifier;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "airport")
    private List<Aircraft> aircrafts = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String aircraftString = aircrafts.stream().map(r -> r.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        return "airport " + name + " " + "[" + aircraftString + "]";
    }
}
```

And a @PostMapping in @Controller like this:

```
@PostMapping("/aircrafts/{aircraftId}/airports")
    public String assignAirport(@RequestParam Long airportId,@PathVariable Long aircraftId){
        Aircraft aircraft = aircraftRepository.getOne(aircraftId);
        Airport airport = airportRepository.getOne(airportId);

        aircraft.setAirport(airport);
        aircraftRepository.save(aircraft)
        System.out.println(airport.toString());
        System.out.println(aircraft.toString());
        return "redirect:/aircrafts";
    }
```

This works. But I can not figure out how does this

```
private List<Aircraft> aircrafts = new ArrayList<>();
```

List get updated?
I first figured it should work like this in @Controller

```
airport.getAircrafts().add(aircraft);
```

But that does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The OneToMany relation in the airport class only reflecting what is persisted in the ManyToOne relation in the aircraft class so whenever you will add a new plane that has an airport, this airport planes List will be updated.
Side Note:
  If you want to achieve the behavior you were expecting you can add

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "airport", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<Aircraft> aircrafts = new ArrayList<>();

 public void addAircraft(Aircraft aircraft){
     aircraft.setAirport(this);
     aircrafts.add(aircraft);
 }
```

to your airport class and then save the airport entity.
but I think this isn't what you want and also it's not beneficial in your current case

Comment: Instead of answering on top of you, I wanted to suggest you demonstrate what you mean by saying `set the this` as it is possible they are not understanding that they need to assign the Parent reference to the child when they add it to the array of aircraft. Help them out with some code and it'll go a long way.

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell Thank you for the hint, I edited my answer